# How to fix this code? It does not scale my images

Tags: html, css

I have this piece of code. It doesn't scale my images to this size.
Height and width doesn't work. Why?

in style.css i have this line:

```
.gallery-popup .image-container img{width: 100%; height: auto; display: block;}


<div class="trace">
                  <img src="img/content/Imagesall/13347.jpg" height="250" width="250" alt="" />
                        <div class="tagline">
                            <div class="content">
                                <div class="title">TITLE</div>
                                <div class="description">TEXT</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>



<div class="overflow">
                <div class="swiper-container" data-autoplay="0" data-loop="1" data-speed="500" data-center="0" data-slides-per-view="1">
                    <div class="swiper-w">
                        <div class="swiper-s"> 
                            <div class="image-container">
                                <img src="img/content/Imagesall/13347.jpg" height="250" width="250" alt="" />
                                <div class="description">
                                    <div class="title">titletext</div>
                                    <div class="text">texttexttext.</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: add css `background-size: cover;`

Comment: I added line: background-size: cover; to my style.css , it doesn't help

Comment: `.gallery-popup .image-container img{width: 100%; height: auto; display: block;}` This line selects nothing in your HTML since there are no elements with `.gallery-popup` or `image-container` classes.

Answer (score 1):

Without any css to look in is this the responsive css for `<img>` images. Give the img a width and set the height to auto. You do not have to use the height and width in the html, use the css to give a width only

```
<div class="trace">
  <img src="img/content/Imagesall/13347.jpg" alt="" />

.trace img {
  width: ...;  /* use for example px or % */
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto; /* this line to preserve width:height ratio */
  border: 0; /* remove default border of img */
}
```

Comment: I can't use trace class.

Comment: I added this but it doesn't fix it.

Comment: Remove the `.trace` , then it will result in `img { .....}` with the 4 lines between the { and }

Comment: In your example is still .trace img
I have checked without trace only img {...} and it doesn't work anyway

Comment: The `.trace img { ... }` means "select all img **in** class="trace". It seems that there is some other css in your stylesheet that interferes with the css above.

Comment: Maybe you are working on the swiper. Then the css has to be `.swiper-s .image-c img { ... }` with the 4 lines between the { and } . This means "select img in image-c in swiper-s" and give those img the css that is specified

Comment: in style.css i have this line:

.gallery-popup .image-container img{width: 100%; height: auto; display: block;}

Maybe this is a problem.

Comment: The line looks fine. Important is the `height: auto` to preserve the correct ratio between width and height. The `display: block` means that the image is full width (a block element) and `width; 100%` does what is says ;)

Comment: Hmm, hard to say without more info. Give this a try `img { width: 100%; max-width: 100%; height: auto !important; border: 0; }` using the !important. Otherwise, do you have a link to the website?

Comment: ok if I add your line my site is destroyed with all big images. I had to remove your line. My website is only in internal network no external. :(

Comment: If I am changing width I see that this is changing.